# Is there a Node.js version of Python's input() function?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to convert some code I wrote in Python to JavaScript, but the Python code used an input() function. Is there a way to get user input through the console in JS?

The Python code was this:

```py
userString = input("Enter a string => ")
answer = getAnswer(userString)
```

Comment: From the NodeJS documentation : https://nodejs.dev/learn/accept-input-from-the-command-line-in-nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prompt-sync:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

const str = prompt('Enter a string: ');
console.log(str);
```

npm install prompt-sync